# mail item's .Categories is blank, but UI shows category was applied

Tags: vba, outlook

When running VBA to apply an email rule to a folder (oRule.Execute), I can visually see the category applied to the mail in TempFolder after code has executed; however, the .Categories is blank / vbNullString when checking the mail's .Categories via VBA.

```
    
    Dim vItem                   As Variant
    
    Dim TempFolder              As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oRule                   As Outlook.Rule
    Dim oRules                  As Outlook.Rules
    
    
    Set oRules = Outlook.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
    Set oRule = oRules.Item("RuleName")
     
    Set TempFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Folders.Add("temporary")

    ' there is code here to move a copy of a mail item into TempFolder

    oRule.Execute Folder:=TempFolder

    For Each vItem In TempFolder.Items

        ' vItem.Categories = vbNullString
        debug.print "vItem.Categories = " & vItem.Categories
        
    Next
```

The code has worked as expected. I'm not sure how it gets into or out of this behavior. I've seen it enter this state after deleting the TempFolder. This behavior happens regardless of where TempFolder is located.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77771726/edit) the post. Describe the minimum number of actions in the rule that produces the behaviour. Put in code that runs [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indicate whether TempFolder is in the default mailbox, a secondary mailbox, a shared mailbox.

Comment: initial edits to post have been made. I'll check the article and comments later to see if more edits are needed

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it because your example is not a minimal one that I can reproduce, but [according to MS itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rule.execute#remarks) it seems that you need to commit the `oRule.Execute Folder:=TempFolder`:

> Use Rule.Enabled **and then Rules.Save** if you want to apply the rule consistently and persist the rules beyond the current session.
> So, as a suggestion before you need to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), do this:

```
oRule.Execute Folder:=TempFolder, ShowProgress:=True '<= just to help debug
oRule.Save '<= here
For Each vItem In TempFolder.Items

    ' vItem.Categories = vbNullString
    debug.print "vItem.Categories = " & vItem.Categories
    
Next
```